# Data won't sort on table (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've written a web app which generates random players and sends them to another component, which renders the data into a table. I did all this using Redux.

Now, as you can see from the code below, the data which is rendered to the table, is taken from the sortedUsers array, which itself takes its' data from the global state.

I've also written a function `sortArray()` in the `SortButton` component, which sorts the given array by time according to the order in which you want it sorted (ascending or descending). The Ascending and Descending buttons in the dropdown menu seem to work fine, because they are sorting the `sortedUsers` array (btw I know this because I logged the array to the console before and after clicking the buttons, and it did work), but for some reason, the table won't re-render the data. So the array does get sorted, but nothing happens with the table.

Here's the component in which the table is rendered:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux/"; //used for accessing values of the state
import { Container, Table, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";
import SortButton from "./components/sortButton";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

function Players() {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.value.players);

  let sortedUsers = [...user]

  const debug = () => {console.log(sortedUsers)}

  const exportHeaders = [
    { label: "ID", key: "id" },
    { label: "Name", key: "fullName" },
    { label: "Email", key: "email" },
    { label: "Gender", key: "gender" },
    { label: "Phone number", key: "phone" },
    { label: "Cell", key: "cell" },
    { label: "Location", key: "location" },
    { label: "Nationality", key: "nat" },
    { label: "Gender", key: "gender" },
    { label: "Age", key: "age" },
    { label: "Times played", key: "timesPlayed" },
    { label: "Time", key: "time" },
  ];

  return (
    <Container>
      <h1 className="mt-3">Players</h1>
      <SortButton users={sortedUsers} />
      <Button onClick={debug}>
        debug
      </Button>
      <hr></hr>
      <Table hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Nationality</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Cell</th>
            <th>Time played</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {sortedUsers.map((player) => {
            if (player.isWinner) {
              return (
                <tr className="table-success">
                  <td>{player.fullName}</td>
                  <td>{player.gender}</td>
                  <td>{player.location}</td>
                  <td>{player.nat}</td>
                  <td>{player.email}</td>
                  <td>{player.phone}</td>
                  <td>{player.cell}</td>
                  <td>{ player.time }</td>
                  <td>{player.isWinner && "Winner"}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            } else {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{player.fullName}</td>
                  <td>{player.gender}</td>
                  <td>{player.location}</td>
                  <td>{player.nat}</td>
                  <td>{player.email}</td>
                  <td>{player.phone}</td>
                  <td>{player.cell}</td>
                  <td>{player.time}</td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              );
            }
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      <CSVLink
        data={user}
        headers={exportHeaders}
        className="btn btn-primary m-3 mt-1"
      >
        Export to CSV
      </CSVLink>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Players;
```

And this is the SortButton:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

function SortButton(props) {
  const sortArray = (array, order) => {
    if (order == "Ascending") {
      return array.sort((a, b) => {
        return (a.time < b.time) ? -1 : ((a.time > b.time) ? 1 : 0)
      })
    }
    return array.sort((a, b) => {
      return (a.time < b.time) ? 1 : ((a.time > b.time) ? -1 : 0)
    })
  }

  return (
    <Dropdown className="mt-3">
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Sort
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {sortArray(props.users, "Ascending")}}>Ascending</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => {sortArray(props.users, "Descending")}}>Descending</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}

export default SortButton;
```

Comment: I think you need to add a `key` prop to your `tr` in the map

Comment: I added `key={player.time}` to it but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that changing the order `sortedUsers` is not updating the state or the redux store, so the component is not re-rendering. You either need to have `sortArray` update the order of the array in the redux store or move `sortArray` to `Players` and do something like:

```
function Players() {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.value.players);
  const [sort, setSort] = useState('ascending')
  const sortArray = (a,b) => {
    if(sort==='ascending'){
      return a.time-b.time
    }
    return b.time-a.time
  }
```

and then in your return statement

```
 {sortedUsers.sort((a,b)=>sortArray(a,b)).map((player) => {
```

and change `SortButton` to just update the state of `sort`